# Best Way to Use WebClient to Send POST Requests with Different Input Values

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to use WebClient to make API calls by sending a integer value as a JSON string in a POST request. I have more than 100K values to send the requests for.

What is the best way to use the WebClient object to do that?

When I call the API in a single threaded loop, using WebClient object as a instance variable and passing the new JSON string for each call, it takes a lot of time.

Is making the calls multithreaded the only solution or is there any way I can make the calls more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given any details how do you get your integers, but here's a simple example to achieve what you want.

Basically you should turn your integers to `Flux` and send each request asynchronously with `.flatMap()` and specify the concurrency factor. From docs concurrency factor is:

> The concurrency argument allows to control how many Publisher can be
> subscribed to and merged in parallel. In turn, that argument shows the
> size of the first Subscription.request to the upstream.

And the code would look like this:

```
/**
 * @param values List of integers
 * @param concurrency concurrency factor. Means how many requests to send at a time
 */
public void sendValues(List<Integer> values, Integer concurrency) {
    Flux.fromIterable(values)
            .flatMap(value -> sendRequest(value), concurrency) // set concurrency factor here
            // proceed with the response here
            .subscribe();
}

public Mono<String> sendRequest(Integer value) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("https://sendvalue.com")
            .bodyValue(String.valueOf(value))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class) // map response body to String
            .doOnNext(__ -> log.info("Successfully sent {}", value)); 
}
```